# How to deserialize a data class that contains another data class

Tags: json, kotlin, jackson, deserialization

I have two data classes A and B

```kotlin
data class A(val b: B, val text: String)

data class B(
    @JsonProperty("b") val number: Int,
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY) val date: String = "",
)
```

My objectmapper is defined like this:
`val objectMapper = ObjectMapper().apply { registeredMoudle(KotlinModule())}`

Main:

```kotlin
val json = "{\"b\": 5, \"text\": \"blabla\"}"
val a = objectMapper.readValue(json,A::class.java)
```

I get a mismatchedInputExeption: cannot constract instance of 'B' (although at least one Creator exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('5')

The thing is when I try to deserialize B on its own it's working. so I don't understand why wouldn't it work on A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the way your json is formatted, b should be an object, not a string.

In order words, with your two class laid out this way, this (the suggested json) won't work:

`val json = "{\"b\": "5", \"text\": \"blabla\"}"`

but this will

`val json2 = "{\"b\": { \"b\": 5 }, \"text\": \"blabla\"}"`

Comment: is it possible to use it with a string map? I mean if we have a map<String,String> and using it with convertValue, because I don't think I can change the json, I get it from a diffrent place

Comment: If you are in the unfortunate position where the value b can be either a string or an object, you will have to set the value of b as `Any` and do the casting and check after Jackson has mapped the object.